# How to retrieve data from Redux store using functional components and avoiding useSelector & useDispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, mapstatetoprops

I'm doing an attemp of Todo App in React- Redux; got store, actions, reducer & Addodo component running; but got stucked at showing todos:

if my initialState=[] how can i retrieve data from store?

Store:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducer';

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer, 
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );

 export default store
```

My reducer:

```
const initialState = [];


const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    // Aca va tu codigo;    
      case 'AddTodo':     
        return [...state, action.payload]; 
        
      case 'RemoveTodo':
        return state.filter(todo => todo.id  !== action.payload)
        
      case 'ToInProgress':             
        return state.map((todo) =>
          todo.id === action.payload ? { ...todo, status: "InProgress" } : todo
        ); 
                     
        case 'ToDone':
         return state.map((todo) =>
          todo.id === action.payload ? { ...todo, status: "Done" } : todo
        );
       
        default: 
        return state
      }
    }
      
 export default todos;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from "react-router-dom"
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from './store/index'

import Nav from '../src/components/Nav/Nav'
import Home from '../src/components/Home/Home'
import AddTodo from '../src/components/AddTodo/AddTodo'
import TodoDetail from '../src/components/TodoDetail/TodoDetail'
import './App.css';

export function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Nav />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/add" component={AddTodo} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={TodoDetail} />
      </Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Todos from '../Todos/Todos'
import './home.css'

export function Home() {
  return (
  
    <div className="todosContainer"> 
    <div>
      <Todos status="Todo"/>
      <label>TODO</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Todos status='InProgress' />
      <label>InProgress</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Todos status='Done'/>
      <label>Done</label>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
};     

export default Home;
```

Here's AddTodo:

```
export function AddTodo() {
   const [state,setState]=React.useState({
     title:"",
     description:"",
     place:"",
     date:"",
   })

  function handleChange(e){ 
    const value=e.target.value;
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]:value
    })
  }

  function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    store.dispatch(addTodo({
      place:state.place,
      title:state.title,
      date:state.date,
      description:state.description
    })) // parameters "id" & "status" loaded in Actions.
    setState({title:"",
    description:"",
    place:"",
    date:"",})
  }

  return (
    <div className="todoContainer">
      <form id="formulario"onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <label>
          Title
          <input type="text" name="title" value={state.title} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Description
          <textarea type="text" name="description" value={state.description} onChange= {handleChange}/>
        </label>
        <label>
          Place
          <input type="text" name="place" value={state.place} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </label>
        <label>
          Date
          <input type="text" name="date" value={state.date} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </label>
        <button className="boton" type="submit" onClick={addTodo}>Agregar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    addTodo: todo => dispatch(addTodo(todo))
  }
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(AddTodo)
```

Now, i want to show at Todos component, every Todos "title", still didn't know how to perform it:

```
export function Todos(data) {
  
  return (
    <div className="todoDetail">

        <h4>{data.title}</h4>  
    </div>
  )
};
  
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    data: state.title,   
  };
  
}   
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Todos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very odd they (code bootcamp) would require you to use a function component and then not allow you to use the React hooks that make the function components so appealing. No worries, you can still use the older `connect` Higher Order Component to inject your redux state and dispatchable actions into the props passed to the component.

You've an issue in `AddToDo` component. You are passing the `mapDispatchToProps` to the `connect` HOC where the `mapStateToProps` callback would be passed. You also aren't using the injected `addTodo` action you just mapped. You almost won't ever need to access the `store` object directly to dispatch actions, use the React components/hooks.

```
export function AddTodo() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    title:"",
    description:"",
    place:"",
    date:"",
  });

  function handleChange(e) { 
    const { value } = e.target;
    setState(prevState => ({ // <-- use functional state update
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]:value
    }));
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addTodo({ // <-- addTodo action injected into props
      place:state.place,
      title:state.title,
      date:state.date,
      description:state.description
    });
    setState({
      title:"",
      description:"",
      place:"",
      date:"",
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="todoContainer">
      ...
    </div>
  )
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addTodo,
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddTodo); // <-- mapStateToProps is null
```

In `Todos` component, your todos state is an array, so you likely want to map it to JSX. Remember to destructure the passed props. Since you didn't share your reducers or how you combine your reducers I'm going to assume there is just one reducer for `todos` located at the state root.

[update]
Since it seems your `rootReducer` is just your `todos` reducer function and I don't see where `combineReducers` is used to build a more complex state tree, `state` ***IS*** your `todos` array state you are trying to pass to `Todos` component.
[/update]

```
function Todos({ todos }) {
  return (
    <div className="todoDetail">
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <h4 key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</h4>
      ))}  
    </div>
  )
};
  
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    todos: state, // <-- state is todos array
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Todos);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer Drew, thank you for taking your time to help me. I'm getting this error:    TypeError: todos is undefined. Trying to undestand...at the return from mapStateToProps, when you call state.todos: my state at Redux says: {title:"some title", place:"right here", description:"some example text", date:"right now", id:"1", status:"In progress"} i was gessing to name it state.title, but wasn't working either. Sorry for my bad english & coding!!!

Comment: @MartinGonzalez I think the issue may lie in your reducers since the UI code you shared and I used in my answer seems to be making some assumptions about the state shape. Can you update your question to add your reducers and how you create your store and provide the redux context (the store provider)?

Comment: @MartinGonzalez So is `state.todos` undefined in `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: TypeError: todos is undefined
Todos
F:/NETBUSTER/HENRY/EXAMEN/CP-M2-FT15a/src/components/Todos/Todos.js:6

  3 | 
  4 | function Todos( {todos} ) {
  5 |   return (
> 6 |     <div className="todoDetail">
  7 |       {todos.map((todo) => (
  8 |         <h4 key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</h4>
  9 |       ))}

Comment: @MartinGonzalez I don't see where you are rendering a `Todos` component. If you are exporting `Todos` and default exporting the connected version, please double check that you are using the default export so it's properly connected to your redux store.

Comment: export function Home() {
  return (
  
    <div className="todosContainer"> 
    <div>
      <Todos status="Todo"/>
      <label>TODO</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Todos status='InProgress' />
      <label>InProgress</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Todos status='Done'/>
      <label>Done</label>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
};     

export default Home;

Comment: @MartinGonzalez Ah, ok, I see we're getting closer, you are rendering several instances of `Todos` on your home page and passing in a filter prop. Sorry if this all seems tedious, can you now update your question to show the `Home` component code and how you import `Todos`?

Comment: Component Home is the landing page, to pass the test, i was asking to render one Todo component for each kind of Status: TODO, In Progress and Done. Those are tasks with i must deal later, after to solve showing todos titles, thats why im bodering you guys....aint sleep in a while and start getting frustrated with this -.-

Comment: @MartinGonzalez Hang in there, we're almost there I think. Can you show *how* you import `Todos` into `Home` file? What I'm suspecting here is that you've imported the named export versus the default export, in other words, I think you've done `import { Todos } from '../path/to/todos';` when you want `import Todos from '../path/to/todos';`.

Comment: Good morning Drew! Todos are imported at Home like:: import Todos from '../Todos/Todos'

Comment: @MartinGonzalez Ok, thanks for confirming how `Todos` is imported. I think I might see the issue now. If `rootReducer` ***is*** your `todos` reducer and you ***aren't*** using `combineReducers` to create a state tree, then I think `state` ***IS*** the todos array you are looking for, and would explain why `state.todos` is undefined. In the `Todos` component use `const mapStateToProps = state => ({ todos: state });` instead.

Comment: Finally!!! It works!!  Drew i have no words to thank you m8!

Answer (score 4):

You looking for [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook.

Do not use `store.getState()` in functional component. Also, you do not need to `connect` functions components, use [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) hook.

Getting values from store will be like this:

```
const todos = useSelector(store => store.items);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Anton! My mistake, ill edit my question. Ain't allowed to use UseSelector or UseDispatch. I wish i can do that! al code examples that i found advice me that

Comment: @MartinGonzalez why you trying avoiding default functionality? In this case, you can use class-components `connect` as you make. `props.data` will be collect your data.

Comment: Thing is Anton, im cursing a Development bootcamp, wasn't able to pass Redux check-point and now im studing to make the checkpòint again. They give me those rules: Can't use useDispatch, no useSelector, must be developed on functional components and the initial State must be just an array (initialState=[])